# How can I use the same random array every time?

Tags: c, arrays

I save the random array on text file so I can load it again. Is there any better way to save it without using txt file?

```
for(i=0;i<10000;i++);
clientdata[i]=rand();

FILE * fp; 
fp = fopen ("client.txt", "w+");
fwrite(clientdata, sizeof clientdata[0], sizeof clientdata / sizeof clientdata[0], f);
fclose(f);
```

Comment: You need to specify the random seed

Comment: What do you mean to specify the random seed?

Comment: You call the file `client.txt` implying that it's a text file, but you don't write a "text" to the file, but the raw binary data of the `clientdata` array. That's most likely won't be anything that can be interpreted as a text.

Comment: You also call the `fwrite` function with the wrong arguments, so you will read *out of bounds* of the array and have *undefined behavior*. If `clientdata` is indeed an array (and not a pointer) then `sizeof(clientdata)` returns the actual size of the array in *bytes*. Using `sizeof(int)` as the elemtn-size will cause it to write four times as much data as you actually have (if `sizeof(int)` is `4` which it most likely is). The first size argument is the size of each element, so `sizeof(int)` is correct here, however the second size is the number of ***elements*** (not bytes) you want to write.

Comment: @user3577378 the random sequence in C is a pseudo-random sequence. It is actually pre-defined. As long as you provide the same `seed`, it will generate the same random number sequence. I put up an answer as an example

Comment: Yes,  it is kind of pseudocode. I just want to find a better solution not to correct this code

Comment: @JoachimPileborg  Correct the code if you want. So the other can see it.

Comment: @user3577378 I don't want to edit your question, but the "correct" call to `fwrite` would be `fwrite(clientdata, sizeof clientdata[0], sizeof clientdata / sizeof clientdata[0], f);` However, it only works if `clientdata` is an actual array and not a pointer.

Comment: What text file?  'FILE *f = fopen("client.txt", "wb");' not opened as a text file.  If yo udid open it as a text file, it woud not work reliably anyway.

Comment: @MartinJames Should be  FILE * fp; fp = fopen ("client.txt", "w+");  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use random seed like this to ensure that you generate the same random number every time:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int seed = 1892; //any number, this is the random seed
    srand(seed); //call this with the random seed argument

    for(i=0;i<10000;i++);
       clientdata[i]=rand();
    //do something, you will generate the same random data every time
}
```

Comment: That is what i was looking for

Comment: @user3577378 yes, knowing that the generated random number is pseudo-random number is the key. :)

Answer (score 1):

The function `rand` from the C library (rand48?) generates a random sequence.

This is however pre-defined.

A different sequence can be chosen using `srand`.  To get the same sequence, use the same value for `srand`.

[example using rand/srand](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_rand.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Use `srand` to start a random number sequence and reuse the same seed value to regenerate the same sequence:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    for(int i=1; i<=2; i++){
        srand (22);        // can be any value -- just the same to restart the series
        for(int j=1; j<=10; j++)
               printf ("Random Number %d: %d\n", j, rand() %100);
    }
    return 0;
}

// regenerates the same series of rand numbers...
```